# How to merge multiple effects in Elm?

Tags: parallel-processing, elm

I have a question about merging multiple effects. My goal is to run N commands (eg Random or Http) in parallel, then merge the results and kick off an update. Think of it an an extension of the [Elm Architecture Dice exercises](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/random.html) for N dice.

I understand you can do this with [`Task.map2`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Task#map2) or [`Task.sequence`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Task#sequence), but I’m looking specifically for parallel execution.

[`Cmd.batch`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Platform-Cmd#batch) sounds like the parallel part I want, but I can’t figure out how to merge the results of the executions.

Here’s [my full Elm code](https://github.com/mLuby/cats-elm/blob/cd15226a4892b9d79de91cdb139060ce5bb6cf49/Dice.elm)
and here's [how I'm guessing at transforming it to act in parallel](https://github.com/mLuby/cats-elm/compare/cd15226...b6a4838) (doesn't work).

For what it’s worth, in JS I’d accomplish this with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Examples)

`Promise.all([promise1, promise2, …]).then(resultsList => …)`

Can’t find anything on this topic online except this, which sidesteps the question: [How to perform multiple Http requests (Tasks) in bulk in Elm lang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39392469/1862046) and this which avoids multiple effects: [How do I add a second die to this elm effects example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227421/how-do-i-add-a-second-die-to-this-elm-effects-example). Hoping this isn't still the case: [Is there parallelism in Elm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181960/is-there-parallelism-in-elm?rq=1) (2015 answer was no).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Elm Architecture, you can fire off a bunch of tasks at once using `Cmd.batch`, but when the results are ready, they will come in as single `Msg` values in the update function, and in no guaranteed order.

Therefore, (at least as of Elm 0.18), you will need to handle "merging" the results yourself since the `Msgs` you fire off will come in one by one. In your Dice example, you would want a single `Msg` constructor for setting a dice value at a particular array index (in this example I used `Array` instead of `List` because you'll be setting a lot by index):

```elm
type Msg
    = Roll
    | NewFaceAt Int Int
```

Now you just need to handle that `NewFaceAt` constructor in your `update` cases:

```elm
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Roll ->
            ( model
            , Cmd.batch
                (Array.toIndexedList model.dice
                    |> List.map (\( i, _ ) -> Random.generate (NewFaceAt i) (Random.int 1 6))
                )
            )

        NewFaceAt index newFace ->
            ( { model | dice = Array.set index newFace model.dice }, Cmd.none )
```

[Here is a working example of the above on ellie-app.com](https://ellie-app.com/3T2zRZNMSPJa1/1).

If you wanted to more closely resemble the `Promise.all([...]).then(...)` example, you would have to bake in some sort of status flag on your model that would be updated every time you receive `NewFaceAt`. For example, your dice could be a list of `Maybe Int`, then when you roll, set them all to `Nothing`, and as dice values come in, you set them to `Just value` and then check to see if all dice values are filled. You could write your view in such a way that you show a "loading" message while the results are still unknown, and only show the images when all results are in. [Here is an example that waits until all results are ready](https://ellie-app.com/3T3b2xbvK8Fa1/0) (granted, it happens so fast that you won't see the loading screen; the effect is more visible when dealing with multiple Http requests).

Answer (score 2):

[Process.spawn](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Process#spawn) will allow you to kick off multiple tasks that the runtime *may* interleave, however there appears to be no way to end up with a single `Msg a` where `a` is some combined result of a number of parallel tasks together.

The notes on the Process page under [Future Plans](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Process#future-plans) seem relevant to your question.

If you'd like to further explore what's possible now and the behavior of `spawn`, I've created an [extension of the more-cats HTTP example app](https://ellie-app.com/3SSXhdKG7h2a1/0), porting some of the helpers from [elm-task-extra](https://github.com/NoRedInk/elm-task-extra/blob/2.0.0/src/Task/Extra.elm) (which hasn't been updated for 0.18).